# Changing element in arraylist

Tags: java

How can I change the element of the ArrayList if the statement is true?

```
ArrayList<String> list;

public void moves(int row , int column , int value) {
  if (list.get(row).charAt(column) == '.') {
    //change this place to the value
  }
}
```

Comment: Well someone already answered with the solution i needed thanks for your input though. i will try to make myself more clear in the future @GhostCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) with the string in the `ArrayList`, then call `setCharAt`. Finally, set the new string back to the array list.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(list.get(row));
sb.setCharAt(column, (char)value);
list.set(row, sb.toString());
```

It might be easier to do this if you use a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>`.

```
if (nestedList.get(row).get(column) == '.') {
    nestedList.get(row).set(column, (char)value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void moves(int row , int column , int value) {
    if (list.get(row).charAt(column) == '.')
        list.set(row, String.valueOf(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is immutable. But, if I understand your question you will want to cast the value to a `char`. Basically, I would start by converting the element to a `char[]` and then update the `list` if I modify it. Like,

```
public void moves(int row, int column, int value) {
    char[] chars = list.get(row).toCharArray();
    if (chars[column] == '.') {
        chars[column] = (char) value;
        list.set(row, new String(chars));
    }
}
```